# How to pass a value to a urlpattern using django templating?

Tags: django, url, django-templates, url-routing

So I have this `urlpattern` where we could type a number on the address bar and it will render an `html template` which will display the entered number on the page, I decided to give it a little more functionality by piping an `add:1` to a links `href` so that every time we click on the link it adds up to the previous number and then generate the response by displaying that number on the page, But I can't get it to work using django templating I keep getting page not found 404 error, Can anyone please help me with this? Here's is the url pattern which accepts an integer

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('home/<int:num>',views.index,name='index')
        ]
```

Here's the HTML template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dynamic urls</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Page no. {{num}}</h1>
        <a href="{url 'home/{{num|add:1}}' }">Change the page</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the right way is to combine `with` statment with `add` filter before passing the new calculated variable to url as second parameter.

```
{% with num_=num|add:1 %}
  <a href="{% url 'home' num=num_ %}">Change the page</a>
{% endwith %}
```

PS

- there should be NO spaces around `=`
- variables should NOT start with `_`
- usual math ops (`+`) are NOT allowed just filters like `add`

Comment: This is giving me ``TemplateSyntaxError Could not parse the remainder: '+1' from 'num+1'``

Comment: i'll update my answer, maybe we need to set num to num + 1 before assigning it in url.

Comment: i updated my answer, let me know if this works for you

Comment: @cizrio Nope, Now it says "``with expects at least one variable assignment``" and this is what my views.py looks like                                                                        
 ```def index(request,num):
    return render(request,"paths/index.html",{'num':num})```

Comment: @ansme i updated my answer and i tested it and it works. PS there should be NO spaces around `=` and variables should NOT start with `_` also usual math ops are not allowed just `filters`, hope this solves your issue.